# A Character Not recognized in C

Tags: c

So this is the program I wrote :

```
  #include <stdio.h>

void main ()
{
    char test='T';
    char test2='10';
    printf("\nFirst- %c" , test);
    printf("\nSecond - %d" , test);
    printf("\nFirst- %c" , test2);
    printf("\nSecond - %d" , test2);


}
```

when I try to compile it and run it I get this error :

```
char.c: In function 'main':
char.c:6:13: warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]
  char test2='10';
             ^~~~
char.c:6:13: warning: overflow in conversion from 'int' to 'char' changes value from '12592' to '48' [-Woverflow]
```

I used limit.h

```
The minimum value of CHAR = -128
The maximum value of CHAR = 127
```

And I see that hypothetically I could insert a value between -128 and 127 . But it don't seems to work. When I put a value between 1 or 9 (only 1 character) the program compile and run. I don't know what to do please help .

Comment: If you want the letter with ASCII code 10 (linefeed), then you can just do `char test2 = 10;`

Comment: A char in c only accepts one character, or an integer value between -128 and 127 (with no quotation marks)

Comment: You're trying to assign a *two-character* literal value. That's 16 bits which usually won't fit in a single char.

Comment: try `char test2 = 10;` or `char test2 = '\x10';` instead ?

Comment: Linefeed (ASCII value `10`) is usually represented by the newline character `'\n'` (which is also portable as linefeed in other encodings, remember that ASCII is not the only one available).

Comment: worked flawlessly when i deleted the quotation mark . Thanks so if I understand correctly  a char number = no '...' and if it is a letter put quotation .

Comment: And with all these comments (and the guess of an answer) you now need to **[edit]** your question to clarify what you really want, and what the code is really supposed to do. Also please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Don't use magic codes. The newline character is spelled `'\n'`, please use it for readability and portability. No one needs to remember what character corresponds to the number 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'10' is not a char. '1' is a char and '0' is a char. '10' is a character array or correctly "10" since ' denotes a single character. You can use:

```
char test2[] = "10";
```

or if you want the char which has the value 10, use:

```
char test2 = 10;
```

But again '10' is not a char. It won't work ever.

Answer (score 1):

The single `'` is to declare a character, so if you put more than 2 characters in it that will be an error. You are fine doing `1` to `9` because they are interpreted as `49` to `57` instead of `1` and `9` as you intended. Get rid of the `'` and use `char test2 = 10` and you'll be fine.

Comment: thanks its worked